# libvlc python binding example: No module named 'evaluator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk, libvlc

When trying to get the example python `libvlc` binding to to run, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evaluator'
```

Here is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install python-vlc
```

Download [example for gtkvlc.py](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob_plain;f=generated/3.0/examples/gtkvlc.py;hb=HEAD) as `gtkvlc.py` and run

```
python3 gtkvlc.py /path/to/video.mp4
```

The offending lines are

```
from evaluator import Evaluator
e = Evaluator(globals(), locals())
e.popup()
```

How can I get this evaluator?

---

**EDIT**: removing the offending lines still leave the application working. What are these lines for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running an old code of gtkvlc.py, try this code it is tested and work very well for Python3 and GTK3

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GdkX11

import vlc

MRL = ""

class ApplicationWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Python-Vlc Media Player")
        self.player_paused=False
        self.is_player_active = False
        self.connect("destroy",Gtk.main_quit)

    def show(self):
        self.show_all()

    def setup_objects_and_events(self):
        self.playback_button = Gtk.Button()
        self.stop_button = Gtk.Button()

        self.play_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-play",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.pause_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-pause",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.stop_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-stop",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )

        self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)
        self.stop_button.set_image(self.stop_image)

        self.playback_button.connect("clicked", self.toggle_player_playback)
        self.stop_button.connect("clicked", self.stop_player)

        self.draw_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.draw_area.set_size_request(300,300)

        self.draw_area.connect("realize",self._realized)

        self.hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.playback_button, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.stop_button, True, True, 0)

        self.vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.draw_area, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False, False, 0)

    def stop_player(self, widget, data=None):
        self.player.stop()
        self.is_player_active = False
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)

    def toggle_player_playback(self, widget, data=None):

        """
        Handler for Player's Playback Button (Play/Pause).
        """

        if self.is_player_active == False and self.player_paused == False:
            self.player.play()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
            self.is_player_active = True

        elif self.is_player_active == True and self.player_paused == True:
            self.player.play()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
            self.player_paused = False

        elif self.is_player_active == True and self.player_paused == False:
            self.player.pause()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)
            self.player_paused = True
        else:
            pass

    def _realized(self, widget, data=None):
        self.vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
        self.player = self.vlcInstance.media_player_new()
        win_id = widget.get_window().get_xid()
        self.player.set_xwindow(win_id)
        self.player.set_mrl(MRL)
        self.player.play()
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
        self.is_player_active = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not sys.argv[1:]:
       print "Exiting \nMust provide the MRL."
       sys.exit(1)
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 1:
        MRL = sys.argv[1]
        window = ApplicationWindow()
        window.setup_objects_and_events()
        window.show()
        Gtk.main()
        window.player.stop()
        window.vlcInstance.release()
```

Comment: I asssume it is from https://www.codementor.io/princerapa/python-media-player-vlc-gtk-favehuy2b ?

Comment: Yes exactly but I tested in my own before I gave it to you.